# Can't use ng-content with mat-form-field

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-form-field, ng-content

I’m trying to do a dynamic form with Angular Material. **ng-content** doesn’t seems to work with **mat-form-field**.

I’m getting this error message:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'errorState') at hostBindings (form-field.mjs:26:94)

Each form field is a module that contains its own component.
Here is what my form looks like (with its 2 components **app-form-field** and **app-input**):

```
<form [formGroup]="form" novalidate autocomplete="off" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <app-form-field>
      <app-input formControlName="input"></app-input>
    </app-form-field>
  </form>
```

**app-form-field** component contains:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="form-field">
  <mat-label class="form-field__label">
    Fill form field
    <span class="form-field__req">*</span>
  </mat-label> 
  <ng-content></ng-content> 
</mat-form-field>
```

**app-input** component contains :

```
<input matInput
  placeholder="Placeholder"
  class="app-input"
  [value]="value"
  [placeholder]="placeholder || ''"
  [attr.disabled]="isDisabled ? true : null"
  (keyup)="onKeyup($event)"
  (blur)="onBlur()">
```

All my module imports look good and I want to point out that if I replace the **ng-content** directly with an input: it works. The issue seems to come from **ng-content**.

I hope someone can help me, I've been stuck on this problem for several days.

**Edit - test without material:**
I have test my logic on angular without material and thats works.
[image]

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you add `fromControlName` directive on an element that is not a form filed component and if you want to create your custom form field component you should use `ControlValueAccessor` interface for implementing the custom component.

Read angular official documentation about [Control Value Accessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) also some papers like [this](https://medium.com/@majdasab/implementing-control-value-accessor-in-angular-1b89f2f84ebf) in `medium` and `dev.to` will help you

Comment: Thanks for you help but if i remove the formControlName i have exactly the same error,  and if i keep my formControlName but remove the mat-form-field thats work great :(

Comment: Because your structure of implementing dynamic forms is incorrect you have to restructure your components and use the right instructions to implement this feature.

Comment: Without angular material all works. I have updated my post with a picture of the result.
I'm using NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR and  ControlValueAccessor for passing data and validation